# How to display text stored in firebase in android?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I am writing a code for displaying the images about the different cities that my company lets the user visits. I want to display the information about what you are gonna do and travelling to the places in the company's list. I have uploaded the information using a text file in firebase storage. And when I click on my activity, I want to display the information using the text file stored in the firebase. I am not able to do so. I have tried using images and have fetched the images from firebase, but I am still not able to fetch text file. How should I do it?

Comment: Looks like you're new to SO. Please provide code to show us what exactly you have tried to do. It would also be a good idea to read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: sorry. that was my first time writing a question to SO and i messed up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello Hope my Answer helps you

first thing is to upload any text into the json format in the realtime data base for example

let me show you how you can do

> firebase console
>   1) go to database tab
>   2)select rules 
>   change them to

```
{
      "rules": {
        ".read": true,
        ".write": true
      }
    }
```

go to data tab create a json like

```
{
      "citydetails" : [ null, {
        "city" : "vizag",
        "image" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/technews-66882.appspot.com/o/techcrunch.png?alt=media&token=fb57c272-be17-459d-aa28-e14f671e7e4f",
        "link" : "https://google.com/",
        "discription" : "some text here"
      }, {
        "city" : "visakhapatnam",
        "image" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/technews-66882.appspot.com/o/thenextweb.png?alt=media&token=7d7c2e44-5fd5-430d-b800-521fc6a57014",
        "link" : "http://google.com/",
        "discription" : "some text here"
      }
    ]}
```

[this screen shot helps you to create json in firebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oo6kR.png)

[this is screen shot create city json object in your case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TCr0w.png)

coming to the code in activity

```
FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase;
 DatabaseReference reference;


firebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        reference=firebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("citydetails");
```

created separate method for better understanding:

```
 private void Traillistners(DatabaseReference databaseReference){
        databaseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                Log.d("checksnap",""+dataSnapshot);
                for(DataSnapshot objects:dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
              // log will shows your result
                Log.d("showdetails",""+objects);
                    }
                }
                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
        }
```

call the method to oncreate method thats it

> adding images into firebase storage 
>   upload image
>   after uploading  to storage

click on image you can see the file location drop down 
copy the image location given and set into json

Comment: should i not use firebase storage for this thing?

Comment: yes add images in firebase storage it will give you link   i will add it into ans

Comment: how could i store the text in textview?

Comment: for saving image in storage   .>    upload image
after uploading  

 click on image you can see the file location drop down 
copy the image location given and set into json

Comment: you will get the the complete json from the child object , you need to add it to arraylist ,, [see the solution in this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38615242/android-how-to-retrieve-list-of-objects-in-their-insertion-order-from-firebase) try this link

Comment: after adding it to arraylist you need to add it into arraylist or get a pirticular object from the children  and the description and add it to text view      1) create model class`City city=objects.getValue(City.class);
                    arrayList.add(city);
                    Log.d("city",city.getName()+"\n"+city.getLink());`

Answer (score 0):

Download file from firebase and use it..

```
Refer this link:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/download-files
```

After download file, read the content from file and display in your textview.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but this is for downloading the files from firebase storage. and i want to display the text from the text file into the textview or something

Comment: Once you download file then after read the content from file and show into the textview....